# Does publishing paginated reports to workspace not require pro license?

Tags: powerbi

My understanding is that publishing a report to a workspace requires the pro license irrespective of whether the workspace is pro or premium capacity.

The following suggests paginated reports don't have this pro license requirement?

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi#prerequisites

> You can publish and share paginated reports in your My Workspace or in
> other workspaces, as long as the workspace is in a Power BI Premium
> capacity and you have write access to the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

This is technically an off-topic question but it's still probably useful.

Microsoft answers this question in [this FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-faq):

> ## Do I need a Pro license to create and publish paginated reports?
>
> You can upload paginated reports to your My Workspace without a Pro
> license, provided it's in a Premium Capacity. For other workspaces,
> you must have a Pro license to author and publish content to them. If
> you have a Premium Per User license, you can convert any workspace,
> including My Workspace, to a Premium workspace. See the Power BI
> Premium Per User FAQ for details. We encourage you to download and use
> Power BI Report Builder even without the Pro license, but you can't
> publish the paginated reports you create without it.

See also [Publish a paginated report to the Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-save-to-power-bi-service):

> ## Requirements
>
> - Either a Power BI Pro license and write access to a workspace in a Power BI Premium capacity.
> - Or Premium Per User (PPU) license.

Comment: Generally for normal reports does user need PRO license to publish report into a premium capacity workspace?

Comment: @variable Yes. See per capacity language here. https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/ "Requires a Power BI Pro license for publishing content into Power BI Premium capacity."